# How to send 2nd Request to server after getting Response from Server ? Using Volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

How to send 2nd Request to server , after getting Response from Server ? Using Volley.

I get response using,

```
private void makeStringReq() {
    showProgressDialog();

    // Instantiate the Request Q
            RequestQueue q=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.GET,
            Const.URL_STRING_REQ, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    msgResponse.setText(response.toString());                       
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hideProgressDialog();
                }
            });      
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
     q.add(strReq);
}
```

my question is , How to send request back once i got the response from server ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void makeStringReq(String url, int method)
    {
        showProgressDialog();

        // Instantiate the Request Q
        RequestQueue q = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(method, url, new Response.Listener<String>()
            {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                    {

                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        makeStringReq(URL_B,Method.POST);
                    }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                    {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        hideProgressDialog();
                    }
            });
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        q.add(strReq);
    }
```

Comment: suppose i get response from URL_A, now i want to set some input fields (like registration form) in the response, then i want to send(POST) the request to URL_B, and so on. And , i want to do all, in the same thread.

Comment: little confusion , what about data i want to post along with 2nd Request ? Either i post String or JSON object .

Comment: you can add it in parameter, if not null then add with request